# How exactly do favored classes work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

According to rules

> Each character begins play with a single favored class of his
>   choosing — **typically**, this is the same class as the one he chooses at
>   1st level. Whenever a character gains a level in his favored class, he
>   receives either + 1 hit point or + 1 skill rank. The choice of favored
>   class cannot be changed once the character is created, and the choice
>   of gaining a hit point or a skill rank each time a character gains a
>   level (including his first level) cannot be changed once made for a
>   particular level. Prestige classes (see Prestige Classes) can never be
>   a favored class.

Emphasis mine.  The word "typically is confusing me. It seems like my favored class does not need to be the same class that my first level is in.  For example, I could roll a level 1 Rogue but choose Wizard as my favored class.

According to my understanding of the rules, when I create a character at 1st level, the favored class must be the one which I choose as a 1st level class and the choice of favored class cannot be changed once the character is created.

If it would be possible, then it makes no sense to me ... Created character at 1st level must choose his favored class ...

It sounds like a way to abuse rules in a way to get more benefits ... f.e. taking Barbarian at 1st level means starting with 12 hit points, instead of 10 HP, when you would not "typically" choose Fighter as a favored class at a 1st level, but after 2nd level following with 20 levels of Fighter ...

Comment: Is the last section you added an observation or do you want it addressed in answers? If you are worried about game changing balance because of 2 extra hp I think you should [check this out](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/2q8j9h/what_is_the_highest_hp_possible/)

Answer (score 9):

You are not required to pick your favored class as the class you choose at level 1. You could pick Fighter as your Favored and then take a level in Ranger or vice versa, it is just **typical** that people choose their first class as their favored.

For example lets say Richard wants to take a dip in fighter for the bonus feat and armor proficiency at level 1, but will then be taking 19 levels in Ranger. It would make much more sense for him to have Ranger as his favored class than fighter.

Comment: @CarlosSatyros by default no. I forgot they gain a bonus point not two favored classes. I believe I was thinking of an alternate racial trait I almost always take, my mistake.

Comment: It's the half-elves.

Answer (score 7):

> So, can I choose at 1st level as a favored class f.e. Wizard, but start at 1st level as a Rogue?

Yes

> According to my understanding of the rules, when I create a character at 1st level, the favored class must be the one which I choose as a 1st level class

No. The requirement is that you have "a favoured class" not that you have "a level in a favoured class".

Answer (score 5):

**Can you pick a favored class different from your actual class at first level? Yes.** The core books explicitly state that this is an unusual thing to do, but it's not against the rules.

**Is it a good idea to do this? If you're actually *playing* at first level, usually not**. It means foregoing bonuses at a time when you're at your weakest.

**But if you're skipping first level, then it can be useful**. Imagine, for example, a character whose backstory involves starting in one class but switching to another at some point before the story begins. This rule allows you to set your favored class to the one you actually intend to *advance* in, rather than being forced by your backstory to make your favored class something you'll never use again.